# Swift unable to preserve order in String made from JSON for hash verification

Tags: json, swift

We receive a JSON object from network along with a hash value of the object. In order to verify the hash we need to turn that JSON into a string and then make a hash out of it while preserving the order of the elements in the way they are in the JSON.
Say we have:

```
[
    {"site1": 
        {"url":"https://this.is.site.com/",
         "logoutURL":"",
         "loadStart":[],
         "loadStop":[{"someMore":"smthelse"}],
         "there's_more": ... }
     },
     {"site2":
          ....
     }
 ]
```

The Android app is able to get same hash value, and while debugging it we fed same simple string into both algorithms and were able to get out same hash out of it.
The difference that is there happens because of the fact that dictionaries are unordered structure.
While debugging we see that just before feeding a string into a hash algorithm, the string looks like the original JSON, just without the indentations, which means it preserves the order of items in it (on Android that is):

```
[{"site1":{"url":"https://this.is.site.com/", ...
```

While doing this with many approaches by now I'm not able to achieve the same: string that I get is different in order and therefore results in a different hash. Is there a way to achieve this?

**UPDATE**
It appears the problem is slightly different - thanks to @Rob Napier's answer below: I need a hash of only a part of incoming string (that has JSON in it), which means for getting that part I need to first parse it into JSON or struct, and after that - while getting the string value of it - the order of items is lost.

Comment: There is `JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.sortedKeys` in iOS 11+ (platform isn't specified). If you can have you back-end and Android sort with that, else, there isn't really, you need a custom JSON Parser...

Comment: that would mean alphabetically sorted right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using JSONSerialization and JSONDecoder (which uses JSONSerialization), it's not possible to reproduce the input data. But this isn't needed. What you're receiving is a string in the first place (as an NSData). Just don't get rid of it. You can parse the data into JSON without throwing away the data.

It is possible to create JSON parsers from scratch in Swift that maintain round-trip support (I have a sketch of such a thing at [RNJSON](https://github.com/rnapier/RNJSON)). JSON isn't really that hard to parse. But what you're describing is a hash of "the thing you received." Not a hash of "the re-serialized JSON."

Comment: yes exactly, the problem is however that we don't need the string of the whole thing, but only of part of it, and to extract that part of it - I do need to first turn it into either json or struct, and that's the moment where things get reordered (or order is lost)

Comment: Look at my RNJSON parser linked above. It'll parse JSON while maintaining the original structure (though I currently throw away whitespace). JSONSerialization cannot do that. It throws that information away before you get it. You can build similar things to RNJSON that will get you to the piece you want without necessarily parsing everything. Look at the tokenizer for how to approach that. You're going to ahve to write something custom or semi-custom in any case.

Comment: There's also some new JSON 5 features in iOS 15 that may be useful. Look at the DecodableWithConfiguration. I *think* you may be able to use that to build something along with OrderedDictionary. (But I don't think there's any easy "keep ordered" switch currently. I believe it's just tools you can use to build this yourself.)

Comment: I used your custom parser, it works like a charm! I am able to now preserve the order and even have more control in other regards. Thanks, Rob saves the day..